# What folder permissions should I set for a Wordpress 3.9.1 install on IIS7?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-7

When you install **WordPress** (`3.9.1` currently) manually through the zip file over at [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org), you're given a folder structure, I've outlined it below but I've only gone two folders deep to illustrate my question.

In IIS7, the default user is **IUSR**

What I'd like to know is, what permissions should I give this file structure so that logged in users can upload files, update plugins as well as the core (with new releases) via the WordPress administration area... **without opening up hack holes**.

Is it safe to allow **IUSR** these permissions on the entire structure? (X, not checked on, O, checked on)

- [X] Full Control
- [O] Modify
- [O] Read & Execute
- [O] List Folder Contents
- [O] Read
- [O] Write
- [X] Special Permissions

I'm afraid that if I open up this gate, that it'll allow **hackers to exploit my server's file system within this website**, potentially opening up more dangerous possibilities. I've read into their suggesstions over at http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions but this document outlines Linux settings, not IIS.  I can't seem to find one for IIS.

```
/* Begin File Structure

/wordpress/
    /wp-admin/
        /css/
        /images/
        /includes/
        /js/
        /maint/
        /network/
        /user/

    /wp-content/
        /plugins/
        /themes/

    /wp-includes/
        /Certificates/
        /css/
        /fonts/
        /ID3/
        /images/
        /js/
        /pomo/
        /SimplePie/
        /Text/
        /theme-compat/
*/
```

Looking at this file structure, it seems that in order to allow people who are logged into the administration area of the website to upload files, update the core, add/remove plugins, I'd have to give the whole thing crazy amounts of access giving anyone the ability to upload anything if they find a loophole in WP's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good resource: http://forums.iis.net/t/1178859.aspx

In summary of that post and from my previous experience on other servers:

You can use the standard permissions for IUSR.

The **theme** / **plugins** / **uploads** folders are what require you to have write permissions. In your example you are missing the uploads folder under wp-content. I would create it manually so you don't want to give wp-content write permissions.

The additonal resouces from the post: 
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/secure-content-in-iis-through-file-system-acls

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/securing-iis-thwarting-the-hacker-week-23